# Automate creating targets in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I'm hoping to build a script of sorts that will enable automation of creating new targets in xcode. I'm in charge of building out many iOS apps that will differ slightly, but all share the same codebase. I'm currently building out each new app with a new target all manually, but would love to automate the process if possible. Any idea on how this could be accomplished?

Fastlane seems to be more geared towards deployment automation.

Comment: You could use [https://tuist.io](https://tuist.io), it's a tool that generates Xcode projects based on the parameters defined in a package description.